# Welcome Activity with background of image

Tags: java, android, xml, android-actionbar, android-theme

I use the theme to show my WelcomeActivity

```
@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen
```

But I found it will have a period of black background when the app start

So I want to change the background of this theme

then I use...

```
<style name="WelcomeTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/welcome_img</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

Although the background is changed , the Actionbar is also showing!!

the Actionbar doesn't show when I use **Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen**

but it's showing when I use **WelcomeTheme**

how should I remove the ActionBar

Thanks for your help :)

-

By the way , in my WelcomeActivity extends Activity but not ActionBarActivity

Comment: Did u add "android:theme="@style/WelcomeTheme" to the manifest?

Comment: yes , I add it in the manifest

Answer (score 0):

Did you try one of those?

in Activity;

```
getActionBar().hide();
```

in Fragment;

```
getActivity().getActionBar().hide();
```

Comment: it doesn't wrok for me :(

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Make you welcome `activity`.

**2.** Go to `styles` xml file and create a `style` like that:

```
 <!-- BWelcome application theme. -->
<style name="WelcomeTheme"      
       parent="android:Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

**3.** Go to `manifest` file and add this to your welcome activity:

```
android:theme="@style/WelcomeTheme"
```

**4.** Add your welcome logo in an `ImageView`

**5.** Advice: Never use `Java` code if you can do it with `XML`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

**WelcomeActivity** extends **ActionBarActivity**:

on **onCreate();**

```
getSupportActionBar.hide();
```

In **Layout** file:

**setBackground** to **Parent View**:

Hope this will help you.